# COUNTIF with multiple AND criteria

Tags: excel

i'm trying trying to count the "customer names" column where the customer names aren't equal to 3 other specific customers and to exclude the count if the cell is blank. anyone? >,<

Comment: Try COUNTIFS (if you are using Excel > 2007) or get inspired by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9583161/count-all-fields-in-an-column-except-for-n-specified-range and show us what your data look like so that we could help you

Comment: Sounds great. Not sure what you want us to do about it.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so as I understand it:

- you have a list of customer names
- you want to count the number of customer names
- you want to exclude names that match three customers (Mr A, Mr B, Mr C)
- and you want to exclude blank cells

I'd use an Array Formula for this.

```
=COUNTA(A1:A20)-SUM(IF(A1:A20="Mr A", 1))-SUM(IF(A1:A20="Mr B",1))-SUM(IF(A1:A20="Mr C",1))
```

Where Mr A, Mr B and Mr C are your customer names, and A1:A20 is your range.

**You will need to press Ctrl + Shift + Enter simultaneously to execute the Array Formula.**

My approach works like this:

- Count the number of non-blank cells in your Customer List range using COUNTA()
- Find how many times "Mr A" appears in the list, and subtract that from your "total customer nan=mes" number.
- Repeat this process for Mr B and Mr C
- IF(A1 ="Mr A", 1) will return 1 if cell A1 contains "Mr A", and otherwise will return 0
- use the range A1:A20 instead of a single cell in the IF() statement and then the Array Formula trick lets you operate on a range of cells.
- SUM() then lets you add up the number of true IF() statements that were found

If you have problems or questions then please do let us know. Ditto if this helps :)

Regards,
GDP

P.S. For more information on Array Formulae (also known as CSE formulae), have a look here: [MrExcel URL](http://www.mrexcel.com/articles/CSE-array-formulas-excel.php)

Comment: You don't really need SUM(IF array formulas when you can just use SUMIF!, e.g. for a single name `=SUMIF(A1:A20,"Mr A")`

Comment: Hmm, actually the SUMIF() approach doesn't seem to work. SUMIF() wants to sum the content of the cells, whereas we want to sum the result of the IF(test, 1) functions. If you can get a SUMIF version working then I'd be curious to see it!

Comment: D'oh! Apolgies @GnomeDePlume, you are correct, SUMIF is no good, `COUNTIF` is what I meant, i.e. this non-array version `=COUNTA(A1:A20)-SUM(COUNTIF(A1:A20,{"Mr A","Mr B","Mr C"}))`

Comment: @barryhoudini: Aha, that looks much neater than my code! Will try to remember that for next time :)

Comment: @user1252333 Glad to have helped. Can you mark the question as  ['answered'](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask), please?

Answer (score 0):

Try COUNTIFS or SUMPRODUCT as per this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9583161/count-all-fields-in-an-column-except-for-n-specified-range) from earlier today, sounds remarkably similar....