# Count if two criteria match - EXCEL formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have this table and I would like to create a formula which would count values based on true conditions from column `A` *and* column `C`.

Example:
If in column `A` value is M (male), and in column `C` is YES, then it would count.

could anyone help me with this formula?

[image: table]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Count all fields in an column, except for n specified range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9583161/count-all-fields-in-an-column-except-for-n-specified-range)

Comment: There's quite a few approaches.  What version of Excel?  You do need to accept some answers.

Comment: Checkout Frequency Method. Single line formula instead of adding extra column and calculation. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14588261/how-to-count-no-in-column-c-base-on-name-id/14591008#14591008

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Add the sheet name infront of the cell, e.g.:

```
=COUNTIFS(stock!A:A,"M",stock!C:C,"Yes")
```

Assumes the sheet name is "stock"

Comment: For anybody looking for a Google Sheets solution, this worked for me:  `=INDEX( SUMPRODUCT( ('Stock'! B2:B100 = "M") * ('Stock'! C2:C100 = "Yes") );1)`  from [this](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/ChcoMdlvKvI) thread.

Comment: Wow - direct copy of two comments 6 months earlier below. Reputation scavenging

Comment: hi how could this done using multiple countif?(I am using openoffice where countifs isnt available).

Answer (score 14):

If youR data was in `A1:C100` then:

**Excel - all versions**

`=SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A100="M"),--(C1:C100="Yes"))`

**Excel - 2007 onwards**

`=COUNTIFS(A1:A100,"M",C1:C100,"Yes")`