# How to count "No" in column C base on Name & Id?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have 3 columns.

```
-----A-----B-----C-----
---Name----ID---Report
```

In column A I have Names(Can Repeat)
In column B I have IDs (can repeat with same ID for different names)
In column C I have Yes and No(Can Repeat with NO for same ID)

I need help to count Number of No's in column C for John(Column A) but only count once if column B has duplicate ID.

I can do this via filters and stuff but I need to do it using formula only please.

Here is file I am working on(dropbox link)
[Dropbox excel file link](http://db.tt/zQm8zgR7)

This is what I got so far

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A1000,"*" & "John" & "*")
```

Comment: This is what I came up so far `=COUNTIF(A1:A1000,"*" & "John" & "*")`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a single formula like this:

`=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(A2:A200="John",IF(C2:C200="No",B2:B200)),B2:B200),1))`

That's an "array formula that needs to be confirmed with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER

That gives 3 for your example - note that it requires column B data to be numeric which seems to be the case here.....

Answer (score 1):

My thought is to add column `D` with the formula `=COUNTIFS(A:A,"="&A2,B:B,"="&B2,C:C,"="&C2)`. This will give you the number of duplicates for each line. If a line returns a 3, then it means there are two other instances of that exact configuration.

Next, create a new table, for testing I did this in columns `G` and `H`. Column `G` is just numbered 1,2,3 etc. beginning in `G2`. The Name is a header and reference in cell `H1`, in this case John. Then put this formula in cell `H2`: `=COUNTIFS(A:A,"="&$H$1,C:C,"=No",D:D,"="&G2)/G2` and drag it down. It is essentially counting the instances of each "1" duplicate, "2" duplicate, and "3" duplicate (which might actually be useful). Then just sum the `H` column and you should have your answer.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be very close to what you are trying to do

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A1000="John")*(C2:C1000="No")*(IF(FREQUENCY(B2:B1000,B2:B999)>0,TRUE)))
```

There is one flaw with the frequency in that it ignores the last row.
If I change the frequency formula to `FREQUENCY(B2:B1000,B2:B1000)` it will error out as it returns 10 results instead of the desired 9.

*EDIT*

It is probably better to extend the other ranges than shorten the bins array.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A1001="John")*(C2:C1001="No")*(IF(FREQUENCY(B2:B1001,B2:B1000)>0,TRUE)))
```

Comment: I don't think you could guarantee correct results with this approach, even ignoring the last row issue, because the conditions are not within the FREQUENCY function - I think that needs to be the case (and also solves any last row issues) as per my suggestion

Comment: The FREQUENCY returns FALSE for any duplicate ID in column B, the SUMPRODUCT will then eliminate any duplicate ID's. This also eliminates the need for an Array formula

Comment: The problem with that approach, Rick, is that the FREQUENCY part is only returning TRUE against the first instance of each duplicate ID in column B......but it may be that John and No will not occur on the row with the first instance......but that they will do on a subsequent instance, in which case your formula won't count that ID, when it does have an occurrence which matches the criteria - If I use your formula for "John" and **"Yes"**, for example, on the given data I get 8 when the result should be 11