# How to count number of "Yes" in column C once only if ID in column B repeats

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I need help counting Yes in column C, but only count it once if ID in column B repeats

Sample of output. for sample below count should be 6. 
Here is dropbox file link.
[Dropbox file link](http://db.tt/iwXgGiYs)
[image]

I can do this already via if and else condition using formula, but I would like someone can come up with better way using single line formula.

**Current solution**
in cell F2

```
=IF(B2<>B1,IF(C2="Yes","1",""),IF(B2=B1,IF(F1="1","",IF(B2=#REF!,"",""))))
```

in cell F3 and down

```
=IF(B3<>B2,IF(C3="Yes","1",""),IF(B3=B2,IF(F2="1","",IF(B3=B1,"",""))))
```

Then I just count all ones and get total 1.

```
=countif(F2:F159,"1")
```

Comment: "but only count it once if ID in column B repeats" - what if the same ID will be in column B, but not in the same sequence, i.e. 1,1,2,1,3 - how many YES we should count for 1?

Comment: my upvote for the nice Q! want more)

Comment: it is for report I am doing, it need simplest way to calculate data because this is repetitive work, and question from yesterday and today is only `"0.10%"` of whole report.

Comment: so we're waiting for more fun from you) Good luck with your report!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a similar approach to my previous answer in your link, i.e. using cell refs in your dropbox example

`=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(I2:I14="Yes",H2:H14),H2:H14),1))`

confirmed with `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`

H2:H14 has to be numeric data

Generically, assuming Range 4 is numeric you can use this formula for up to 3 conditions

`=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF((Range1="x")*(Range2="y")*(Range3="z"),Range4),Range4),1))`

conditions can be added or removed as required

Comment: Brilliant, works as expected) Passed QA ©, got upvote. BTW your `FREQUENCY` solutions make me feel ugly)))

Comment: After he posted that frequency solution, I am trying to learn it too but can't http://www.exceluser.com/solutions/q0001/frequency.htm

Comment: @Mowgli please correct ranges: `=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(I2:I14="Yes",H2:H14),H2:H14),1))` shows 6 for your sample file.

Comment: @PeterL. I did correct range, moved data to new sheet and pasted it there.

Comment: I added a "generic" version which will hopefully show you how to modify for more or less conditions - note if "range4" isn't numeric it gets more complex....!

Comment: Sorry, it worked without problem, I just closed and open file again. Man you are genius. You need to do a tutorial or something. please

Comment: `>it is showing me 7` - sounds like you haven't use CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER correctly - do you have { and } around formula?

Comment: @barryhoudini it worked!!! :).. just so I understand how it works, if you can answer, if I just try this formula `FREQUENCY(IF(C2:C159="Yes",B2:B159),B2:B159)` it returns me 1. why does it calculate the count ?

Comment: Frequency returns an "array" - if you put that formula in a cell you will probably only see the first value of the array - try selecting the cell with the formula, then press F2 followed by F9 - you should then be able to see the whole array, e.g. something like `{0;0;0;0;1;2;0;0}` - the SUM(IF part returns 1 for every value >0 so in that example the result would be 2

Comment: Thanks, I will try to play with Frequency and F2 and F9, I was able to see the array, I will need to spend more time on it to understand it more. thanks a lot for great help.

Answer (score 1):

Put this in D2 and drag down:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS(B$2:B2,B2,C$2:C2,"Yes")=1,1,"don't count")
```

Comment: Thanks..better formula then mine. I don't want to use drag down method, I want to use single line formula which would do all of this. check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14588261/how-to-count-no-in-column-c-base-on-name-id/14591008#14591008