# Using Excel Countifs() with multiple criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I'm attempting to use the countifs() function, however, I keep returning a value of 0. This is the dataset:

```
   |   A  |    B  |      C     |
   | item1| 3/3/14| 12:00:15 AM|
   | item2| 3/3/14| 12:00:39 AM|
   | item4| 3/3/14| 12:05:19 AM|
   | item1| 3/3/14| 12:05:19 AM|
```

I tried the following countifs() to count all the items that fit this criteria:

```
=countifs(A:A,"item1",B:B,"3/3/14",C:C,"12:*")
```

So I want this function to grab "item1" in column A, 3/3/14 in B, and anything that starts with "12:". So this should return a value of 2, but it's not. Any ideas?

Comment: Your data are all text? or Actual date and time? That is the key. Try formatting it as `General` then use the value the cell displays in your `Countifs`.

Comment: @L42 If I convert my times to general then it looks like 0.0334234 and I can't really make sense of that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10158675/count-if-two-criteria-match-excel-formula

Comment: @JohnSmith You only need to do that to see what you will put in the condition. See my post.

Comment: @L42 I'm not sure what you mean. I'm an excel newbie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To explain my comment, refer to below:

[image: Sample Data]

As you can see, I have time values in `C7:C8` and `D7:D8` respectively in different formats.
To get what you want, it's like basically counting all entries less than `01:00:00 AM`.
So to get your formula to work, use this formula instead:
`=COUNTIFS(A$2:A$5,"Item1",B$2:B$5,"3/3/2014",C$2:C$5,"<" & 0.041667)`

**Edit1:** As commented, you can use reference cell as well. In above, it is C8 or D8.

`=COUNTIFS(A$2:A$5,"Item1",B$2:B$5,"3/3/2014",C$2:C$5,"<" & $C$8)`

**Edit2:** As commented, what you want is possible but not using `CountIfs`

[image: sumproduct]

Above we used this:
`=SUMPRODUCT(1*(A2:A9="Item1"),1*(B2:B9=DATEVALUE("3/3/2014")),1*(C2:C9>TIMEVALUE("2:00:00 PM")),1*(C2:C9<TIMEVALUE("3:00:00 PM")))`

We use the `SUMPRODUCT` function.
A bit more complex formula for a bit more complex requirement of yours. :)

Comment: Dude, so awesome! I can't thank you enough, man! I've been beating my head against the wall on this one! :) What if I wanted to get times in between 12:00:00 AM & 1:00:00 AM? Sorry for the extra question, but it would be super helpful!

Comment: That's exactly what the formula does. Since you are counting all that is `< 0.04167`. Equivalent of `12:00:00 AM` is `0` and `1:00:00 AM` is `0.04167`. To increase precision, increase the decimal place like this `0.0416666666666667` or use a reference cell to put the `1:00:00 AM` value.

Comment: Well I guess to better rephrase my question is what if I wanted to grab like times between 2:00PM & 3:00PM and other time intervals? Salamat po!

Comment: I see that I can reference the cells, but I have a very, very large dataset and so I'll have to use specific times intervals. Is there actually a way to do this?

Comment: Not by using `CountIfs` I guess.

Comment: But ofcourse what you want is possible. See my edit. And again, not by using `CountIfs` but a more complex formula.

Comment: COUNTIFS is possible, e.g. `=COUNTIFS(A:A,"Item1",B:B,"3/3/2014",C:C,">=14:00",C:C,"<15:00")`

Comment: @barryhoudini Cool. I was overthinking I guess. :). John forget about the SUMPRODUCT then :)