# How to count the amount of times a unique event happens in Excel?

Tags: excel, countif

I have a range and I want to count the number of times a value appears in column 1 and no values appear in the other 3 columns on the same row.

Here is an example of the data I'm working with:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/jR7W5lq.png]

So for this data the answer should be `4`.

Comment: What version of Excel are you using? 2007 & later have a modified version of the `countif` function that allows for multiple criteria. See `countifs`.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10158675/count-if-two-criteria-match-excel-formula/21625201#21625201 for approaches that work pre and post [tag:excel-2007]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,"Seen",B:B,"",C:C,"")
```

Comment: is there a way to make it count any cell that has a value instead of searching `"Seen"`? something that would function like `COUNTA`

Comment: that doesn't seem to work for me. http://i.imgur.com/T56YlfQ.png sometimes the value in the 1st column is not "seen" but i still want the formula to count those values.

Comment: my apologies, so it does :) ty

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`=COUNTIFS(A:A,"Seen",B:B,"",C:C,"")`