# Using Excel formulas to find a substring in cells when condition is met

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to search for a given sub-string in column `D` when conditions are met in columns `A` and `B`.

A simple `countifs` as suggested in the question [Count if two criteria match - EXCEL formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10158675/count-if-two-criteria-match-excel-formula) does not match because I would like the ingredient (*Chocolate* in my example) to be **part of** the values and not an exact match like in that question. It is therefore NOT a duplicate question.

Let's say I own a restaurant (I wish :) and I have this:

1. Column `A`: the category of a dish
2. Column `B`: the price range of the dish
3. Column `C`: the name of a dish
4. Column `D`: a list of ingredients in that dish

[image: List of ingredients in each dish]

I want to search if any of the **main** course that is **expensive** contains **chocolate** (i.e. putting in a cell the value `FALSE`, `"No"` or `0`). It could look like something like that

[image: Expected]

I don't want to do this by using VBA but rather using Excel Formulas.

Really appreciate your help.

Thanks

**[NOTE]**:
The difference with the suggested related question is to add `*` in the matched strings. Although a small difference, it is what made me ask the question in the first place.

Comment: @brettdj Similar question but not duplicate. The difference lied in the `"*"` it the criteria.

Comment: My view (which is subjective) is that is a minor difference, furthemore the other question provided answers that work for all excel versions, hence better others get directed to that. Good that you got an answer here though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`CountIfS` is your friend here

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,"Main",B:B,"Expensive",D:D,"*chocolate*")>0
```

Comment: How can I have forget the `*<text>*` !~! Thanks so much. This was the formula I tried to use but with `Find` it was not working well :)

Comment: @Jean-FrancoisT. If this worked for you, don't forget to mark it as the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Enter into E2:

```
=AND(A2="Main",B2="Expensive",IFERROR(SEARCH("Chocolate",D2)>=0,FALSE))
```

And drag down.

Comment: Also it is a valid answer, it would require to copy-paste in multiple rows. This didn't fit my needs where the formula to search criteria is already dragged down (criteria for "B" is varying). Thanks again for your time and quick answer.

Comment: @Jean-FrancoisT. Understood. I had assumed you wanted a new column that answers the question for each row.

Comment: Indeed the question was not 100% clear. Updated :)