# Excel rows count using counting formula involving multiple columns

Tags: excel-formula

I'm struggling to take a count of rows in excel sheet (using formula) involving 3 columns of data say `a`, `b` & `c`. The condition is having value `111` in column `a` besides column `b` or column `c` having a 100. So, it is like

```
a2:a500="111" AND (b2:b500=100 OR c2:c500=100)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count if two criteria match - EXCEL formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10158675/count-if-two-criteria-match-excel-formula)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
=COUNTIFS(A2:A500, "111", B2:B500, "100") + COUNTIFS(A2:A500, "111", C2:C500, "100", B2:B500, "<>100")
```

Comment: This won't work because if for example A2 = 111, B2 = 100, and C2 = 100, your formula will erroneously count that entry twice. You can modify the second `COUNTIFS` to account for this, i.e. `COUNTIFS(A2:A500, "111", C2:C500, "100",B2:B500,"<>100")`

Comment: @SwapanGhosh Does that fix it?

Comment: @Tripp Kinetics yes, that does...thnx

Comment: @TrippKinetics How do I upvote and accept...pls explain.

Comment: Click the grey checkbox next to my answer to accept.  Click the up arrow next to my answer to upvote.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((a2:a500=111)*((b2:b500=100)+ (c2:c500=100)>0))
```

Comment: It does have the same problem of double counting as mentioned by imagineryHuman072889

Comment: @SwapanGhosh To fix, do this: `=SUMPRODUCT((a2:a500=111)*((b2:b500=100)+ (c2:c500=100))>0)`